# Temperature based data lake

Tags: azure-data-lake

I recently come across a term Temperature based data lake , I searched for information about it, but couldn't able to find anything related to it. Could someone please explain what does it means and share any links. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you say temerature based data lake , I am assuming that you are refering to hot and cold tier .

Hot - Optimized for storing data that is accessed frequently.
Cool - Optimized for storing data that is infrequently accessed and stored for at least 30 days.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers

HTH .